# iTunes doesn't allow me to create playlists and playlist folders anymore

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, playlist

I'm a bit stumped. So I was trying to add some MP3s to my iPhone 5 using iTunes and it simply doesn't react to the clicks on the respective symbols anymore.

Here's a partial screenshot:

[image]

The shown playlists and playlist folders are contained in a parent playlist folder, which was selected prior to attempting to add a playlist.

The two controls at the bottom with the plus and the cog don't work. It's as if they're disabled, but it's hard to tell for me in this Apple-style GUI.

Does anyone have an idea how I could convince iTunes to let me create (smart) playlists and playlist folders again?

NB: this is the music "tab" and I have opened the "Device" node for my iPhone on the left hand side and selected the parent playlist folder there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it in 'device' do it 'on the compy' in Music/Playlists - should be underneath the device list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I need to do it on the device. The device contains smart playlists and playlist folders which don't seem to be fully in synch with the PC (unlike the media themselves, which are in synch).

Comment: You can't do it from the device listing, as you already discovered. You might be able to do it on the phone itself, I've never tried.

Answer (score 1):

You must manually manage your music, go to iTunes -> select the device -> Summary

[image]